# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND while running electron App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, build, electron

I have an app written in typescript. I create a build running `npm run build`. A folder dist is generated where different sources are saved:

[image: Folder structure]

I get Automatically the following script `index.html` with the following code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>IAV Translate</title>
    <base href="./">
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index-dbf8fcb6.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/index-69a98e9f.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I created an electron app to wrap the TSX app in an other folder as follow (final purpose: get an exe file):

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

// Inside file1.js
const path = require('path'); // If you're using Node.js

// const targetFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html');
// const targetFileContent = require(targetFilePath);


// mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

function createWindow() {
  // Create a new browser window
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false, // Enable Node.js integration
        //   webSecurity: false, // Disable web security (not recommended for production)
            // nodeIntegration: false, // Disable Node.js integration
            contextIsolation: true, // Enable context isolation
            sandbox: true, // Enable the Electron sandbox
            contentSecurityPolicy: "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"


            
        },
    });

    // Open the DevTools for debugging (add this line)
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    // Build the path to your index.html relative to main.js
    const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html');

    // Load your React app's HTML file
    // mainWindow.loadFile('../dist/index.html');
    if (isDev) {
        mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000').catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error loading URL:', error);
        });
      } else {
        mainWindow.loadFile(indexPath).catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error loading file:', error);
        });
      }
      
      
}

// Create the main window when the app is ready
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
  })
```

The package.json of the electron app is as follow:

```json
{
  "name": "electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-package ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^26.3.0"
  }
}
```

[image: Folder structure]

When I run npm start to open the app, the app opens but not all resources are found:

[image: Errors]

I tried multiple solutions like adding:

```html
 <base href="./">
```

Or calling the resources directly in the body but nothing worked. From my research, it is a problem that has to do with the path of the resources. Any ideas?

**Update**
I updated the `vite.config.ts` file to be like this

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), svgr()],
  server: {
    port: 3000
  },

  base: "./"

})
```

and run  `npm run build` again. This eliminated the error but the resources still don't load. When opening the dev tools, these resources don't show at all [image]

Answer (score 1):

For Vite + Electron you have to set the [public base path](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#public-base-path) to `./` or `""` (value for [embedded deployment](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base)) for your assets to load correctly:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  base: "./"
})
```

Note that this should only be required in production, in development you're supposed to use the dev server.

Comment: Thank you @Arkellys!! The errors are gone but still the electron app didn't show any huge differences. Only the image is being loaded. The other resources i.e. .ttf, .woff and woff2 don't show on the isolated context. In other words not all resources are loaded.

Comment: @sffgsfgs I can't really help more with the information you provided. It's not clear if you're trying to run your application in development or in production. You can check the network tab to see if the problem comes from the paths.

Comment: I want to run it in production. Can you explain why it's not clear?

Comment: @sffgsfgs For me it's not clear because you said you use `npm run build` which is usually the command to compile the react app and not to package an Electron app (but then, you didn't share what this script does). You also said you use `npm run start`, which is for dev only. And finally, you haven't said which packager you use nor what's its config.

Comment: I have a react app. I run `npm run build` to get the build. I wrapped this build using electron. I added the code of the `main.js` file above. Then I run the electron app using `npm start`. I am still testing if all resources are loaded to electron, that's why I still didn't get to the phase of usage of any packager. Maybe the steps I am following are wrong, this is my first time doing this. Do you think anything missing?

Comment: @sffgsfgs You can't develop an Electorn app like this. In dev, you start your local server and load the `localhost` into the Electron window (meaning starting your app with vite serve and then starting electron with `electron .`). In prod, you build the app and load the HTML file into Electron. Packaging the app means building it for prod: creating the installable (exe) file. In prod you can only "start" the app by installing it on your computer, not by running a script.

Comment: I suppose your resources are missing because your start Electron in dev while your server is not running.